# SVG editor in JavaScript, cannot edit after upload files

Tags: javascript, svg

HTML  file

```
<div id="center">
                <svg class="paint" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    </svg>
 </div>


 <input type="file" accept="image/svg+xml" id="file" class="btn btn-secondary" />
```

JS part:

```
$('#file').on('change', function (file) {
         var imageFile = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
         if (imageFile) {
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.readAsText(imageFile, 'UTF-8');
             reader.onload = function (e) {
                 svg.outerHTML = e.target.result;
             };
         }
         console.log(imageFile);
     })
```

My problem is that after the page load the .svg file, it will appear successfully on the page edit part, but I cannot edit its element. And the editor works well if I do not upload file. Any help is appreciated.

---

sample drawing function

```
 //tool for straight line
 function tool_line(action, x, y) {
     //console.log(action);
     switch (action) {
         case "mousedown":
             console.log(current_tool);
             if (!mouseisdown) {
                 return;
             }
             startx = x;
             starty = y;
             break;
         case "mousemove":
             if (!mouseisdown) {
                 return;
             } else {
                 console.log(current_tool);
                 $(current_marker).remove();
                 current_marker = svg_line(startx, starty, x, y);
             }
             break;
         case "mouseup":
             console.log(current_tool);
             $(current_marker).remove();
             svg_line(startx, starty, x, y);
             break;
     }
 }

 function svg_line(startX, startY, endX, endY) {
     var newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'line');
     newElement.setAttribute("class", "svgobject");
     newElement.setAttribute("stroke", 'black');
     newElement.setAttribute("fill", 'none');
     newElement.setAttribute("stroke-width", "3");
     newElement.setAttribute("x1", startX);
     newElement.setAttribute("x2", endX);
     newElement.setAttribute("y1", startY);
     newElement.setAttribute("y2", endY);
     newElement.setAttribute("id", gid++);
     newElement.setAttribute("transform", 'translate(0,0)');
     svg.appendChild(newElement);
     return newElement;
 }
```

Comment: how are you trying to edit the content?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thx, I have added the one drawing function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#file').on('change', function (file) {
     var imageFile = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
     if (imageFile) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsText(imageFile, 'UTF-8');
         reader.onload = function (e) {
             svg.innerHTML = e.target.result.slice(70, -6); //!important
         };
     }
     console.log(imageFile);
 });
```

Instead of using outerHTML, I tried innerHTML.Now problem solved perfectly. I guess using the outer HTML will erase the event listener based on the former svg element, so just using the slice() method to read the svg element inside the svg tags, and put it into the origin svg tags, make it.